# how to store database values in an array with comma seperated values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am looking to store the database values which are already stored as id's and retrieve via a for each loop within an array.

I have tried something like this, but it is not working:

```
foreach ($list as $item)
{
     $commaSeparated = implode(',' , $item['id');
}
echo $commaSeparated;
```

Where `item['id']` is the specific column pulled out of the query.  If I use the $list variable, then I am getting the full result of the query which I do not want.

But, my error results in this:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed
```

This is what has correctly returned what I need:

```
foreach ($list as &$id)
        {

            $listArr[] = $id['toolbar_id'];

            $commaSeparated = implode(',' , $listArr)

                             echo $commaSeparated;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you need to perform

```
$commaSeparated = implode(',' , $list);
```

It is not a good practice though. You should never store the lists as comma-separated items in database. Instead - create additional table for it and store 1 item per row.

Comment: I miscommunicated my issue.  The items are coming from the database already.  They are single id values.  I am trying to store each one of these values which are pulled from a query into an array.  Although if I use $list as the value to store in the array, it does not pull the specific column value as I would want.  I will edit my question above.

Comment: @Brandon Ellis: you need to rephrase your question obviously then

Comment: Yes. I just have. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `implode` needs to be an array. Try this:

```
$commaSeparated = implode(',', $list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Implode function accepts a separator and an array for parameters. Then you should do this:

```
$commaSeparated = implode(',' , $list);

echo $commaSeparated;
```

(Source: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you trying a var_dump($variable) where $variable is the ...variable, in which the data is stored, knowing its structure will tell you what data to expect and how to iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more checks to avoid the error if your data is not in correct format.

```
if(is_array($list)){
    foreach ($list as $item)
    {
        if(is_array($item)) 
            $commaSeparated = implode(',' , $item);
    }
    echo $commaSeparated;
}
```